# Pygame orbit simulation issue

Tags: python, pygame, physics, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

I have recently been making a orbit simulator using this equation: [image: Picture of Equation I am using]

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Planet():
    def __init__(self, vel = [1, 1], mass = 100000, pos = [100, 100], pathLength = 100000):
        self.v = vel
        self.m = mass
        self.size = mass/1000000
        self.pos = pos
        self.pL = pathLength
        self.path = [[pos[0], pos[1]]]

    def update(self):
        self.pos[0] += self.v[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.v[1]
        self.path.append([self.pos[0], self.pos[1]])
        if len(self.path) == self.pL:
            self.path.pop(0)

class World():
    def __init__(self, planetList, iterations, mass = 10000000, gravityConstant = (6 * 10 ** -9)):
        self.plnt = planetList
        self.iter = iterations
        self.mass = mass
        self.size = int(mass/1000000)
        self.gC = gravityConstant
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0, 0, 0], [250, 250], self.size)
        for p in self.plnt:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 0], [p.pos[0], p.pos[1], p.size, p.size])
            pygame.draw.lines(screen, [0, 0, 0], False, p.path)
    def update(self):
        for i in range(self.iter):
            for p in self.plnt:
                d = math.sqrt((p.pos[0] - 250) ** 2 + (p.pos[1] - 250) ** 2)
                f = (self.gC * self.mass * p.m)/(d ** 2)
                vect = [((250 - p.pos[0]) / d) * f, ((250 - p.pos[1]) / d) * f]
                p.v[0] += vect[0]
                p.v[1] += vect[1]
                p.update()
        self.draw()


a = Planet([4,0])
b = Planet([4, 0])
w = World([b], 100)
while 1:
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])

    w.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

If i just have 1 planet in the simulation it works as expected, but with this it has issues

```
a = Planet([4,0])
b = Planet([4, 0])
w = World([a, b], 100)
```

The planets fly off the screen and continue on forever, I cannot see where i have made a mistake.

Comment: Unrelated to your particular problem your implementation is not exactly how gravity works. You have one central "world" exerting gravity on "planets" without being influenced itself. And your "planets" do not influence each other at all. In reality all objects exert gravity on each other in a pairwise fashion and if A exerts a force F on B then the force exerted on B from A is -F. So technically you need a nested loop and compute all the pairwise relationships once (the opposite direction is redundant as stated above). Make sure to pick the signs right as the equation does not provide them.

Comment: @MartinKrämer Yes this is how I wanted to implement this but yeh i could easily alter if to exert forces between the central body and then other.

Comment: [Try using an IDE](http://sopython.com/wiki/Python_IDEs). It will help you immensely both in writing better code as well as in learning to program. Personally I use PyCharm which would notify you of default mutable arguments, but probably other IDEs have similar functionality.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Which one would you recommend

Comment: You are using the force as acceleration, but force is mass times acceleration. You should work on being able to use smaller step sizes. And you should replace the symplectic or semi-implicit Euler method by a higher order method, like Verlet or some Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: @LutzL I am very new to simulations would you be able to point me in the direction of some good resources to learn off of. Thanks

Comment: One nice site is ["Moving stars around"](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web), which has code examples for several methods in a Ruby and a C version.

Comment: @adammoyle I have only used PyCharm, so i can't give you a non-biased suggestion. PyCharm (when used non-commercially) is free though, and has _amazing_ features. You can search google "best IDE python", though some results will be either obsolete or simply promotions of products. If you choose PyCharm check those [vids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rSBPGGLkW0)

Comment: @Fermiparadox Totally agree with Fermi here - PyCharm is fantastic. And recently JetBrains released a new EAP version of Rider which seems to be an amazing cross-platform IDE for C# too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fell for the age-old Python trap of declaring mutable default arguments. :)

To cut to the chase so you can get your code working, copy the replacements I've made below into your own code:

```
class Planet():
    def __init__(self, vel = [1, 1], mass = 100000, pos = [100, 100], pathLength = 100000):
        self.v = vel[:]  # Added [:] to ensure the list is copied
        self.m = mass
        self.size = mass/1000000
        self.pos = pos[:]  # Added [:] here for the same reason
        self.pL = pathLength
        self.path = [[pos[0], pos[1]]]
```

**Explanation**

In Python, lists are *mutable* - you can modify the same instance of a list. One common mistake that people make when using Python is to declare mutable arguments as default values within function signatures.

The problem is that Python will assign that default value *once* to the parameter at the time that the function definition is processed, and then *reuse* that assigned value each time the function is invoked and the default argument called upon.

In your `Planet` class constructor, you're declaring two mutable default arguments:

- `vel = [1, 1]`
- `pos = [100, 100]`

Every instance of `Planet` you create will store a reference to these lists, but note that because of what I said above, every planet will share the *same* `vel` list and the *same* `pos` list. This means each instance will interfere with the velocity and position data of the others.

You can read more about this gotcha [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/).

An alternative and preferred way of handling situations like this would be to set the default value as `None` and then assign the "real" default value if the caller doesn't provide an explicit value for it:

```
class Planet():
    def __init__(self, vel = None, mass = 100000, pos = None, pathLength = 100000):
        self.v = vel or [1, 1]
        self.m = mass
        self.size = mass/1000000
        self.pos = pos or [100, 100]
        self.pL = pathLength
        self.path = [[self.pos[0], self.pos[1]]]
```

You would then be expected to document this behaviour of the function, since it would not be apparent to the caller otherwise.